# Why doxygen doesn't read doxygen comment

Tags: documentation, doxygen

When I run the doxygen config file not all the comment are correctly read from doxygen. I have notice that all the comments don't read are declared inside the main or in the body of other func. Why? Which flag in the config do I need to change? [Here a pastebin of the code](https://pastebin.com/ejAjc010) Sorry for the comments in Italian.

```
int main() {

//---------------------------------VARIABILI PER LA GESTIONE DEL MULTIPLEX-----------------------------

    int serverSocket; /**< Socket dove il server ascolta e accetta le connessioni dei client */

    int dataSocket; /**< Socket usato dal DTP del server per eseguire le richieste dei client */

    int fd_clients_sockets[FD_SETSIZE]; /**< contiene gli fd dei client */

    fd_set command_fds; /**< insieme degli fd disponibili a ricevere comandi dai client */

    int max_client_fd; /**< rappresenta il valore più alto tra gli fd **/

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; /**< buffer di servizio per conservare i comandi ricevuti 
*/
```

Reading the doxygen manual I tried different type of comments and it  doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? The mentioned variables and comments are internal to the subroutine and as such of no direct interest for the documentation. You can have a look at the command `\internal` and the setting `INTERNAL_DOCS`.